# RSpec. How to test method with nested private method (mocking/stubbing)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Comrades, how to test method "self.default" with nested private method "self.merge_op"? I`m noob in RSpec. What is more suitable for such case: mocking/stubbing?
Functionality of file - it`s some kind of MailClient

```
class MailClient
  def self.default
    options = self.merge_op
    @clients[options] = MailClient.send :new unless @clients.has_key?(options)
    @clients[options]
  end

def self.merge_op(opts={:smtp => {}, :pop3 => {}})
def_smtp_opts = {:address => settings.mail_smtp_server,
                 :port => settings.mail_smtp_port,
                 :domain => settings.mail_smtp_domain,
                 :user_name => settings.mail_smtp_user_name,
                 :password => settings.mail_smtp_user_pass,
                 :authentication => 'plain',
                 :enable_starttls_auto => true}

end
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with basic rspec code showing what actually you are trying to test ?

Or at least basic description of what you are trying to test ?

Answer (score 1):

I would just test the `default` method without regards to the fact that it uses a private method to do its work. Figure out what the expected outputs for given inputs are.

The primary reason I say this is that it makes your tests more robust. You can change the internal workings of the `default` method, maybe even eliminating the private method, without changing the test.

The only thing I would think about mocking is whatever the `settings` object is in the private `merge_op` method. That object is effectively an input to the `default` method.